# apollo server mutation resolver not called

Tags: graph, apollo-server

This is my schema

```js
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    users(pagestart: Int = 1, pagesize: Int = 10): UsersResponse
    user(id: ID!): User!
    me: User
  }

  type Mutation {
    addUser(user: UserRequest): UserResponse
    updateUser(user: UserRequest): UserResponse
    login(user: UserRequest): UserResponse
    logout: UserResponse
  }
```

This is my resolvers

```js
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    // ...
  },
  Mutation: {
    addUser (_, { user }, { dataSources }) {
      return dataSources.UserDatasource.addUser(user)
    }
  }
}
```

When I sent a mutation, the resolvers mutation was not invoked. I added consoon.log in resolvers Mutation, which did not print on the console. Resolvers' Query is all right. Any good Suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My personal mistake

Please don't mind

Comment: You could've shared with us what the problem was :)